# Reply From < IP address >: Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: ping

This is the first time I've delved into this and stumped as to what is causing the issue. I've setup a network as follows:

DC: 10.1.1.20
SRV-A: 10.1.1.22
SRV-B: 10.1.1.24
SRV-C: 10.1.1.26
SRV-D: 10.1.1.28

I am able to ping all servers except SRV-C to SRV-D and vice versa. I get the below error:

Reply From 10.1.1.26: Destination Host Unreachable
Reply From 10.1.1.26: Destination Host Unreachable
Reply From 10.1.1.26: Destination Host Unreachable
Reply From 10.1.1.26: Destination Host Unreachable
...
Reply From 10.1.1.28: Destination Host Unreachable
Reply From 10.1.1.28: Destination Host Unreachable
Reply From 10.1.1.28: Destination Host Unreachable
Reply From 10.1.1.28: Destination Host Unreachable

I have disabled the firewalls, changed IP addresses and rebooted the machines but nothing seems to work.

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use the same `netmask`on all of them? which one?

Comment: @Jarmund Such a firewall setup would normally result in timeout, not destination host unreachable.

Comment: yeah the subnet mask is all the same. 255.255.255.0. I configured the firewall settings on SRV-C and SRV-D to match the configuration settings on the other servers so I guess it cant be that

Answer (score 0):

First, be absolutely sure these pc's actually have these IP Addresses. Also be sure no other pc or device uses these ip adresses. If you have a DHCP server, make sure this is not giving out IP Addresses in this range.

If all this works, see if these servers can ping other servers, such as the domain controller. It is likely that a cable is unplugged if a server has no connectivity at all.

But if a server can ping another but not a third, and the same applies for that server, it is more likely there's a duplicate ip issue. For example, both servers could actually have the same ip.

Comment: i've been able to ping all servers except between SRV-C and SRV-D. I can ping SRV-A to SRV-C and vice versa or DC to SRV-D, just not SRV-C to SRV-D and vice versa. The IP's are static also.

Comment: Odd. Only thing I can imagine, is that there's some hidden relation between the servers. For that reason, I would recommend rebooting all servers, one at a time, starting with the DC, and depending on what the other servers do, they might be dependend on eachother and need a certain order. For example, use this order: Domain controllers, database servers, file/print servers, terminal servers.

Comment: Also, make sure the server is fully up and running before booting the next.

Comment: I finally got it working. I have set these machines up in virtual box. I simply refreshed the MAC address for both servers in the virtual machine settings. Thanks for your help.